# What Node.js does besides serving web applications?

Tags: node.js

I'm aware that I can use node.js to build web applications. 
Can I use it for system administration tasks? Stuffs not initiated by outside users. Like daemons or cron tasks.
I believe Python is better for such stuffs.. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What Node.js does besides serving web applications?

It runs JavaScript of pretty much any kind you like

> Can I use it for system administration tasks?

Yes

> Stuffs not initiated by outside users.

Yes

> Like daemons or cron tasks.

Yes

> I believe Python is better for such stuffs.. Am I right?

Bah, Perl is the best.

(Without specific criteria by which you want to determine "better", this is highly subjective).